# Enabling sidebar on Python-Sphinx documentation based on a sphinx-bootstrap-theme

Tags: python-sphinx

I am using the nice sphinx-bootstrap-theme 0.3.4 and trying to apply it on top of Sphinx Python Documentation Generator version 1.2.

When I build the documentation via `make html`, I don't get any sidebar, although it's shown to be possible in this [example](http://ryan-roemer.github.io/sphinx-bootstrap-theme/sidebar.html). Neither, I was able to find any option to enable sidebar in the build configuration file (conf.py).
Doing the following:

```
html_sidebars = {'sidebar': ['localtoc.html', 'sourcelink.html', 'searchbox.html']}
```

doesn't help.

Thanks for any hint on how it's possible to enable sidebar from such a Sphinx theme.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just figured it out.  This should do the trick.

```
html_sidebars = {'**': ['localtoc.html', 'sourcelink.html', 'searchbox.html']}
```

Using this as a reference

[Sphinx theming guide html_sidebars](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-html_sidebars)

I am experimenting with creating a custom sidebar since I don't like the included options.  Using the bootstrap demo index.html I created the following for a custom sidebar.  Just name it something like `my_custom_sidebar.html` and put it in /source/_templates

```
<ul class="globaltoc"
>{{ toctree(maxdepth=theme_globaltoc_depth|toint, collapse=False,includehidden=theme_globaltoc_includehidden|tobool) }}</ul>
```

Then edit `html_sidebars`

```
html_sidebars = {'**': ['my_custom_sidebar.html', 'searchbox.html']}
```

Comment: it is throwing error for `theme_globaltoc_depth`.
Just in case, remove it.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was after. Saved my time!